# In data.table in R, how can you reference columns that have `<=` in their names without making R think its an operation?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose we have the following `data.table` object in `R`, and we wish to subset the data by those where `x<=0.5 == 1`:

```
x=rnorm(1000)
df <- data.table(x=x, `x<=0.5`=1*(x<=0.5))
df[`x<=0.5` == 1]
```

This returns an error saying:

`Error in .parse_on(substitute(on), isnull_inames): Found more than one operator in one 'on' statement: x<=0.5==x<=0.5. Please specify a single operator.`

How can I actually reference it without this error? I assume it is because it thinks the less than or equal sign is not a name but an operation.

Comment: Any reason why you can't change the names to valid ones, rather than trying to work around invalid names?

Comment: This is likely an over-eager optimization within the `data.table` code, always trying to find things in the `i=` and `j=` components that are operators versus operands, and things that can be optimized into internal code. While it might be a bug for the `data.table` maintainers, I don't know that this will garner a lot of immediate attention. (But I think you should still [ask them](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new/choose) and let them decide :-).)

Comment: @camille We wanted a report where the printed variables are showing the relation with `<=`. It would be possible for us to change it and then revert back for printing, but wanted a more efficient method. thanks

Comment: Seems to be a regression of this (closed) issue: [Strange behavior when subsetting with column names quoted with backticks in I of data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2931). One of the workarounds shown there works (at least in devel version): `df[(`x<=0.5`) == 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `get` on a string to return the value

```
df[get("x<=0.5") == 1]
```

-output

```
               x x<=0.5
  1:  0.3903123      1
  2:  0.1426477      1
  3: -0.3169492      1
  4: -1.3024570      1
  5: -1.5403663      1
 ---                  
691: -0.4453730      1
692: -2.3406638      1
693: -0.3276438      1
694:  0.4063935      1
695: -0.5860276      1
```

---

Or use it in `.SDcols`

```
df[df[, .SD[[1]] == 1, .SDcols = "x<=0.5"]]
```